# вот мой код смотрите Grundy пожалуйста

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, s = 0;
    string t;
    getline(cin, t);

    for (i = 0; i <= t.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (t[i] == ' ')
        {
            s++;
        }
    }

    s++;
    string a[s];

    for (i = 0; i <= s - 1; i++)
    {
        while (t[j] == ' ')
        {
            a[i] = a[i] + t[j];
            j++;
        }

        j++;
    }

    int r = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= s - 1; i++)
    {
        if (a[i].length() > r)
        {
            r = a[i].length();
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= s - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = a[i].length() - 1; j <= r - 1; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = '#';
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= s - 1; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что делает этот код? Что должен делать этот код? Стоило добавить его непосредственно в [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1029702/186999) и укать что именно с этим кодом не так: ошибка в момент компиляции, ошибка в момент выполнения, выдает неверный результат?